# how to validate value of two input posting their value as json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two input datepicker and i am sending their value by

```js
var getData = basePath + 'AdminFinance/GetStudentPaymentsForDate/?FromDate=' + 
    $(".datepickerInputFROM").val() + '&ToDate=' + $(".datepickerInputTO").val()
if ($(".datepickerInputFROM").val() == 'null') {
    alert('error')
}
```

I am using alert box if .datepickerInputFROM value is null.
Please help how to validate for both .datepickerInputFROM and .datepickerInputTO.

Comment: `if (($(".datepickerInputFROM").val() == 'null') && ($(".datepickerInputTO").val() == 'null')) { ... }`

Comment: I don't think the value will ever be the string ``null``. If they haven't filled in the datepicker, it will be an empty string `''`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney wouldn't it be better to use `||` - or  rather than `&&`? The error will only run if both are `==` to null.... You want to alert the error if any of those values are `==` to null.... or as Barmar has pointed out == `''` to nothing/empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply check for them both:

```
if (($(".datepickerInputFROM").val() == 'null') && ($(".datepickerInputTO").val() == 'null')) { ... }
```

If you want to check if either are empty, use `||` which is `or`

```
if (($(".datepickerInputFROM").val() == 'null') || ($(".datepickerInputTO").val() == 'null')) { ... }
```

Checking against a string of `'null'` is not ideal by the way and it will fail if empty is what you're checking for - for empty it should be

```
if ($(".datepickerInputFROM").val() === '') ...
```

Or you can just do

```
if ($(".datepickerInputFROM").val()) ...
```

Comment: It should probably be `||` not `&&`

Comment: Yeah it should be the OP does say the word `and`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney the OP is saying **and** to point at multiple validations *"validate for both "* not **and** as in both must be null.

Comment: @NewToJS well he could be, I agree, updated the answer to cover more bases